# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Endroid\QrCode\Builder\Builder

Tags: php, composer

Установлена библиотека https://github.com/endroid/qr-code
на сервер.

Отдает ошибку: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Endroid\QrCode\Builder\Builder" not found in`

На локалке все работает, на сервере не хочет. Я думаю что `psr-4`, на локальном это есть в `composer.json` а на сервере нет. Но при добавлении и обновлении композера и очистки кеша, ничего не помогает.

Переустановил все пакеты, композер заново поставил вместе с `psr-4` - результат тот же.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было при инициализации композера в вопросе:

```
Would you like to define your dependencies (require) interactively [yes]?
```

Написать `yes`